# Excel VBA to SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba, excel

I've just started looking into interacting with an SQL database via Excel VBA, and I started off with the basic connection code from MSDN:

```
Sub GetDataFromADO()
'Declare variables'
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=fatcoin;User ID=root;Password=root;"
    objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    strSQL = "select * from productlist"

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

'Copy Data to Excel'
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
End Sub
```

The issue I'm having is while I have an SQL instance running on my machine, on port 3306, which I can access using for example, HeidiSQL, every time I run this code I get an error message:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied

I have also tried adding a port:

```
 objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost,3306;Initial Catalog=fatcoin;User ID=root;Password=root;"
```

And other such things. I can't see any reason it shouldn't work, but I haven't played with this much at all. I've tried searching through other threads to no avail.

Any ideas?
I am working with Excel 2010, on a 64-bit Machine, using MySQL 5.7
I should mention the above coding is being inputted into the "Module1" section of the VBAProject on Excel.
Thanks

Comment: You say you have a mysql server, but you are trying to connect to an ms sql server. Install 64-bit myodbc from mysql's website, then check out the connection string on connectionstrings.com

Comment: I'm a little confused here. I already have myodbc due to my developers installation of MySQL.
I checked out connectionstrings.com and it seemed to indicate the same connection string as I already have listed.
It has a different string too, with Provider=MySQLProv but Excel says that is not a valid provider

Comment: When I check out connectionstring.com, then for 64-bit myodbc I see the following example: `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;
User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;` This is completely different from yours. But you can use the myodbc's GUI to create a connection as well, which you can use from Excel.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help.
I did try that connectionstring, before I even posted here, and got
"Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: Also pointed out above this coding is being done in the Modules section of Excel's VBAProject

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.
I solved my own question via a helpful link I found that suggested I go into ODBC 32-bit (because Excel is 32-bit) and create a System DSN. Then, I used the connections string below:

```
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=root;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=fatcoin"
```

It worked a treat.